# None of Paramiko's Read methods work for me?

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I have this class I've written:

```
class Remote(object):
    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        self.address  = address
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def stdout(self, s):
        print('out: ' + s)

    def stderr(self, s):
        print('err: ' + s)

    def sh(self, s):
        from paramiko  import AutoAddPolicy, SSHClient
        from threading import Thread
        from time      import sleep

        ssh = SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(self.address, username = self.username, password = self.password)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(s)

        def monitor(channel, method):
            while True:
                for line in channel.readlines():
                    method(line)
                sleep(1)

        Thread(target = monitor, args = (stdout, self.stdout)).start()
        Thread(target = monitor, args = (stderr, self.stderr)).start()
```

Then I try running it like this:

```
>>> from remote import Remote
>>> address  = <removed>
>>> username = 'root'
>>> password = <removed>
>>> r = Remote(address, username, password)
>>> r.sh('echo Hello')
```

And I get no output. If I change the monitor method around so instead of:

```
for line in channel.readlines():
    method(line)
```

I have simply `method(channel.read())` or `method(channel.readline())`, but in that case, I just see:

```
out:
err:
```

Once a second - it never actually gives me the expected results of:

```
out: Hello
```

I know that my address, username, and password are all right, because I can feed them into `fabric` just fine.

```
>>> from fabric.api        import env
>>> from fabirc.operations import sudo
>>> env.host_string, env.user, env.password = address, username, password
>>> sudo('echo Hello')
[<omitted>]: Hello
```

What am I doing wrong in my `paramiko` based class which `fabric` is evidently able to handle?

**Edit**

I want the method to by asynchronous. It should return immediately. For example, if I do this:

```
r1 = Remote(<one set of credentials removed>)
r2 = Remote(<another set of credentials removed>)
r1.sh('echo Hello; sleep 5; echo World')
r2.sh('echo Hello; sleep 5; echo World')
```

Then the results should be:

```
out: Hello
out: Hello
out: World
out: World
```

Indicating that the two calls ran in parallel, not:

```
out: Hello
out: World
out: Hello
out: World
```

Which would indicate that the two calls ran synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `while True` loop in `monitor` prevents the thread to end. Leaving the first part as is and changing the last lines to:

```
def monitor(channel, method):
    while True:
        l = channel.readline()
        if l:
            method(l)
        else:
            break
tout = Thread(target = monitor, args = (stdout, self.stdout))
terr = Thread(target = monitor, args = (stderr, self.stderr))
tout.start()
terr.start()
tout.join()
terr.join()
ssh.close()
```

will print the output of the given command line by line, while there's something to be returned.

Comment: I want to have the methods run asynchronously. It shouldn't wait until the command finishes to return. If the user of the class cares about what the command outputs, they should subclass and use the `stdout` or `stderr` methods.

Comment: I don't think you do understand - that still results in the calls being synchronous. I've added an edit to my question to explain. Having said that, your code actually outputs something, whereas my original code output nothing, so +1 for that. Further, I'll let you know that making this synchronous was actually pretty easy. All I had to do was change the name of `sh` to `_sh` (to indicate it's private), and make a new `sh` which just starts a thread and runs `_sh` on it, then returns without joining. Not sure if that's the most elegant solution or not, but it seems to work.